# How does relfinder work,how does it work to find paths between different sparql endpoints

Tags: sparql, rdf

How does relfinder work, how does it work to find paths between different sparql endpoints, are there other open source tools like this, or how does it work to find paths between different endpoints?
I wanted to implement the ability to find two node paths from different endpoints, but relfinder only works in flash.Are there any methods or tools.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX  : <http://www.example.com#>
SELECT * WHERE {
<http://www.example.com#A> (:|!:)* ?x .
?x ?p ?y .
?y (:|!:)* <http://www.example.com#E> .
} LIMIT 10
```

I have tried this query, but it can only query directed graph, not undirected graph

Comment: it simply tries longer paths in the RDF graph, starting from length 1, i.e. a single triple pattern.

Comment: *"I have tried this query, but it can only query directed graph, not undirected graph"* - why? you can also check for the other direction in the property path. Clearly, SPARQL is a less appropriate language for path querying or traversal. In that case, other languages working on graphs would work better and do have the more natural syntax in my opinion.

Comment: Because the data is stored on different servers, if use graph database, need to put all the data into one database, which cannot achieve the effect of distributed query. relfinder（http://www.visualdataweb.org/relfinder.php） can query paths from different endpoints without importing data. I also want to achieve this effect, but don't know how

 @UninformedUse

Comment: what exactly do you want to know now? Exploring paths on a triple store can be achieved via simply increasing the number of triple patterns each of those representing one more hop in the graph. Federated querying can be achieved via `SERVICE` keyword. So all you have to do is to set a SPARQL endpoint URL for the public hosted dataset you're interested in, created a SPARQL query that checks for paths of length 1 to length n and then you can visualize that in your client app